# Get StopID from of TransitStop

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google directions api, using 'transit' mode.
Part of the result is the `transit_details` object, which contains the stops information (`arrival_stop` & `departure_stop`).

The questions is how can I get the StopID? The `*_stop` objects contain only location and name. On maps.google.com though, the results do contain the Stop ID.

Google transit_details:

```
 "transit_details" : {
                        "arrival_stop" : {
                           "location" : {
                              "lat" : 32.181194,
                              "lng" : 34.871078
                           },
                           "name" : "XXXX"
                        }
```

Here you can see what I'm speaking of. I chose an arbitrary station on google maps, and you can see it gives the Stop ID for it.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say 'maps.google.com has the Stop ID'? I can't find what you're talking about

Comment: @TylerEich, please see my edit, and let me know if you need any extra info.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Uniquely identify transit stations? What do you want to use this ID for? There might be other solutions depending on what you are trying to do...

Comment: The uniquely identify transit station, yes. I need it in order to spot that station in the static GTFS feed.

Comment: It's not a perfectly nor correctly way. I would inspect and get the parent/children or class/id then get his value by js or jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this right now. Google doesn't provide those details yet sadly.

Answer (score -1):

first you need to assign that id to the

```
 "arrival_stop" : {
                           "location" : {
                              "lat" : 32.181194,
                              "lng" : 34.871078
                           },
                           id:urID
                       "name" : "XXXX"
```

then u can retrieve on any event

Comment: I need to assign the ID?! The ID is according to GTFS, not something I determine.